# Schema restriction for neo4j

Tags: mongoose, neo4j, odm

I am new to neo4j, coming from NoSQL(MongoDB) background. In case of MongoDB, Mongoose is the Object Document Mapper (ODM) I used. It helped me to define the Schema. I am looking for something similar for neo4j.

I use Node.js backend to connect to neo4j using neo4j-driver package.

So what I expect is:
I should define type of my nodes and the properties with data types.

eg 
Node: {
label: "Person", 
"attributes": {
"name": "String",
"mobile": Number, 
"isOnline": "Boolean"
}
}

This would help me write robust code. Without this some developer can make mistake in spelling of "Person" or "mobile" and a new node type or attribute will be created.

What is the best way to achieve this in neo4j ?

Comment: Search for Neo4j OGM (Object Graph Mapper). It sounds like you are asking for something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tezra. OGM is exactly what I needed. Have a nice day !